# How to customize email page

Tags: page-layout

Is there a way to customize the email page for emails?

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate what do you mean by customizing ? You want to add more fields or change from email id ?

Comment: Add fields and buttons @Dave

Comment: This is proposed as an Idea on Idea Exchange.. https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Brdr ..It is not supported at present.  However you may do custom programming to achieve this.

Comment: @Dave that'd make a great answer :-)